# Front-end vibrations in Pontiac G6

Tags: troubleshooting, wheels, pontiac, vibration, g6

**Car:** 2007 Pontiac G6 (3.5L engine)

**Problem:** Front-end vibration

**Details:**

- I feel the vibrations primarily in the steering wheel. However, I also slightly feel it in my foot resting on the gas pedal and floor and ever so slightly in my seat.
- The vibrations start around 20-30mph but continue through at least 80mph
- I feel it while going straight and also while turning.
- There is no sound (humming, banging, etc); just the feeling of vibration.
- Braking doesn't seem to worsen or fix the issue.

**What could be causing this?**

**Notes:**

- I just replaced the wheel hub/bearing on my front right wheel.
- I've quadruple checked the lugnuts -- they're tight on both front wheels.
- I think my front right brake caliper is stuck, but I do not think this is the source of my vibration because the pads are not smoking or burning, so could it really be dragging that badly??
- tires appear to be in good shape with relatively even wear. (Nothing suspect).

**My Thoughts**:

- Since the vibration is constant at most speeds, it seems unlikely to be a wheel balance issue.
- I don't think it's a wheel hub issue because I also don't hear the growling/humming sound I heard when the old one went bad.

  - However, the vibration only arose *after* my work on the right wheel hub, so I wonder if I screwed something up??? (Seemed to simple to screw up).
- CV joint also seems unlikely due to a lack of "clicking" on sharp turns.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you didn't throw a wheel weight on the front of the car?  It happens, and will certainly give you a vibration.

Comment: Lots of things this could be. You said you replaced the wheel hub/bearing. Are you saying that the vibration was NOT there before that? Does the vibration get worse with speed? Or stay the same? When was the last time the wheel/tires were balanced? Just because CV joints don't "clink" doesn't mean there isn't anything wrong.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I only assumed it wasn't a wheel balance issue because the vibration doesn't "come and go" as I increase speed -- which is typically how a balance issue manifests.

Comment: @CharlieRB I realize this could be lot's of things. I cannot be sure about the vibration not being there before replacing the wheel hub because of the vibration the hub was making. I can be sure, though, that if it was there it was never as noticeable as it is now. I would also say the vibration has progressively gotten worse SINCE I replaced the hub -- suggesting something post-hub-replacement is getting worse.

Comment: @CharlieRB I wouldn't say the vibration gets worse with speed, but the vibrations do change in frequency to match the speed of the car. The wheels were last balanced about 6mo ago.

Comment: @CharlieRB what other signs could I look/listen for to determine if it is possibly the CV joint(s)??

Comment: I guess my point is that because it could be so many things, there really isn't a way for us to answer this. It is possible the wheel bearing on the other side is going bad too. Could be a bad motor/trans mount allowing engine vibration to be felt in the car.  It might not be drivetrain related...could be exhaust pipe vibrating against the body. As far as CV joints, I was just making a point that just because they aren't clicking doesn't mean they aren't vibrating.

Comment: @CharlieRB I gotchya . Yes I understand it's difficult to narrow down, but I guess my hope was that people such as yourself would provide other possibilities that I haven't thought about and any typical diagnostic tips to help me narrow things down on my own...

Comment: Was the axle nut torqued to spec? Have you tried rotating the tires?

Comment: @Ben Yes the axle nut was torqued to spec and then confirmed with a 2nd torque wrench to double check. I have not rotated the tires in about 4k miles